# Android 10 : Drawable Image fade issue (Whities Backgrund)

Tags: android, xml, angular-material

In the below, there are two images one UI is perfect(You can see the Image behind the numbers) but the second one (With pinkies background) somehow and sometime drawable image fade out and appearing pink color with that image I am totally confusing what is the issue behind I have tried my side every solution but cant help.

[image: This is the correct output]

[image: Somehow this output came]

**A small reference of my XML code is:**

```
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="?android:windowBackground">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:translationY="@dimen/card_corner_radius_large_minus"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_top"
                    style="@style/CardViewStyle.Large"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="266dp">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_theme"
                            coil_path="@{contest.themeImage}"
                            coil_blur="@{true}"
                            coil_placeholder="@{@drawable/login_bg}"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            tools:src="@drawable/login_bg" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_contest_layer_with_theme"
                            android:visibility="@{contest.themeImage == null ?  View.GONE :  View.VISIBLE}"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/top_view_scheduled_timer"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88">

                            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt_ticket_no"
                                android:layout_width="74dp"
                                android:layout_height="74dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_round_yellow"
                                android:text="@{numberAppear, default = `-`}"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/be_vietnam_extra_bold"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:textSize="29.67sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                />

                            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_socket_connection_state"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_connection_status"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
                                android:paddingVertical="8dp"
                                app:cornerRadius="20dp"
                                android:minWidth="0dp"
                                android:text="@{connectionState}"
                                tools:text="@string/socket_connect_error"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semi_bold"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:alpha="@{connectionState == null || connectionState.equals(``) ? 0f : 1.0f}"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                />

                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_win_info"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@color/snackbar_success_bg"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                tools:text="@string/socket_state_connecting"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semi_bold"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:alpha="0"
                                tools:alpha="1"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                />

                            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/rv_ticket_no"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_ticket_no"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                                android:clipToPadding="false"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                tools:itemCount="5"
                                tools:listitem="@layout/row_game_play_ticket_no"
                                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                                />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/toolbar_margin_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toolbar_margin_top"
                    android:background="@{contest.themeImage == null ? @drawable/toolbar_bg_light : @drawable/toolbar_bg_dark}"
                    app:menu="@menu/contest_detail">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="?titleTextAppearance"
                        android:text="@{contest.name}"
                        tools:text="Tajmahal Quiz" />
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
 </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
```

Help me if anyone knows about these issues.

Answer (score 0):

So many attempts but sometimes its silly mistake but not mine its regarding Coil image loading library issue
I remove fade animation for displaying images and the issue has been resolved.